# Working with time values greater than 24 hours

Tags: python, time

How does one work with time periods greater than 24 hours in python? I looked at the `datetime.time` object but this seems to be for handling the time of a day, not time in general.

`datetime.time` has the requirement of `0 <= hour < 24` which makes it useless if you want to record a time of more than 24 hours unless I am missing something?

Say for example I wanted to calculate the total time worked by someone. I know the time they've taken to complete tasks individually. What class should I be using to safely calculate that total time.

My input data would look something like this:

```
# The times in HH:MM:SS
times = ["16:35:21", "8:23:14"]
total_time = ? # 24:58:35
```

Comment: The point is that these are not times but *durations*, and the representation of a duration is a `timedelta`

Comment: Yeah, I realise that now. When I was reading the available types for `datetime` the `timedelta` had a misleading description in that it was the difference between `datetime` classes. It doesn't state that it can be used for durations so I didn't read any deeper into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, you want a sum of all times and not difference. So you can convert your time to [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and then sum it:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
# get hours, minutes and seconds
>>> tm1 = [map(int, x.split(':')) for x in times]
# convert to timedelta
>>> tm2 = [timedelta(hours=x[0], minutes=x[1], seconds=x[2]) for x in tm1]
# sum
>>> print sum(tm2, timedelta())
1 day, 0:58:35
```

Comment: Thank you! The `datetime` docs are misleading, the summary for `datetime.timedelta` states it's used for calculating the difference between the `datetime` classes. It doesn't describe that it is, infact, a generic time class.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is not a builtin way to construct [timedeltas](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) from strings (like `strptime()` for `datetime` objects) so we have to build a parser:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> import re

>>> def interval(s):
        "Converts a string to a timedelta"
        d = re.match(r'((?P<days>\d+) days, )?(?P<hours>\d+):'
                     r'(?P<minutes>\d+):(?P<seconds>\d+)', str(s)).groupdict(0)
        return timedelta(**dict(((key, int(value)) for key, value in d.items())))

>>> times = ["16:35:21", "8:23:14"]    
>>> print sum([interval(time) for time in times])
1 day, 0:58:35
```

EDIT: Old wrong answer (where I misread the question):

If you substract datetimes you get a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object:

```
>>> import datetime as dt

>>> times = ["16:35:21", "8:23:14"]
>>> fmt = '%H:%M:%S'
>>> start = dt.datetime.strptime(times[1], fmt )
>>> end = dt.datetime.strptime(times[0], fmt)
>>> diff = (end - start)

>>> diff.total_seconds()
29527.0

>>> (diff.days, diff.seconds, diff.microseconds)
(0, 29527, 0)

>>> print diff
8:12:07
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime` returns a `datetime.datetime` object which again can't handle a period of more than 24 hours. Try: `>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("25:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.  They want to know the how long the **sum** of the given times is, not the difference.   The times are not absolute times on the clock, but the length of time to complete a task.

Comment: @Lerp, You are both right, I read the question too fast. Now should be better.

Comment: To be fair, my post was less about converting the string to an object and more about storing a duration which `timedelta` is for (as I now know)